# Python Selenium - Disable Chromedriver log message in cmd

Tags: python, logging, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I can't disable chromedriver logging message "DevTools listening on ws:......" in cmd, i've used some methods like,

1. options.add_argument("log-level=3")
2. options.add_argument("disable-logging")
3. options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])

but the message "DevTools listening on ws:....." still appear in the cmd.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("log-level=3")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-logging")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"credentials_enable_service": False, "profile.password_manager_enabled": False})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), service_log_path = "NUL", options = options)
browser.set_window_size(360, 720)
browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Network.setUserAgentOverride", {"userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.53 Safari/537.36"})
browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/")
sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe a little late but this worked for me

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('urllib3.connectionpool')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger('selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection')
logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Hope this help